# How to move marked character based on text selection in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, algorithm, byte-shifting

I want to move the marked `_#current selected text#_` exactly around the current text has selected. So let's see in an example.

1. **Step 1:** still no text has selected, so the String is:

   `let stringVal = "Hello friends, let's program with javascript";`

---

2. **Step 2:** `Hello friends` has selected, so the String is:

   `stringVal = "_#Hello friends#_, let's program with javascript";`

---

3. **Step 3:** `Hello friends, let's` has selected, so the String is:

   `stringVal = "_#Hello friends, let's#_ program with javascript";`

   As you can see, here `let's` added to the selection text so the end of mark `#_` moves `ahead` to the same size of `, let's`.

---

4. **Step 4:** `with` has selected, so the String is:

   `stringVal = "_#Hello friends, let's#_ program _#with#_ javascript";`

   As you can see, here `with` separately marked as `_#with#_`, because it's not attached to the **previous** text nor the **next** text.

---

5. **Step 5:** `gram with javascript` has selected, so the String is:

   `stringVal = "_#Hello friends, let's#_ pro_#gram with javascript#_";`

   As you can see, here `gram` added **before** `with`, so the starter mark `_#` moves `back` to the same size of `gram`, on other hand `javascript` added **after** `with`, so the end mark `#_` moves `ahead` to the same size of `javascript`.

---

6. **Step 6:** `let's program` has selected, so the String is:

   `stringVal = "_#Hello friends, #_ _#let's program#_ _#with javascript#_";`

   This Step is complex, as you can see, here `let's` and `gram` **re-selected** and `pro` added **after** `let's` and **before** `gram`, so the starter mark `_#` moves `back` **before** `let's` and end mark `#_` moves `ahead` **after** `gram`. Also we should be careful about `_#Hello friends,` as it doesn't have end mark so we must added `_#Hello friends, #_` and also `with javascript#_` doesn't have `starter mark` so we must added `_#with javascript#_`.

---

7. **Step 7:** `let's program with javascript` has selected, so the String is:

   `stringVal = "_#Hello friends, let's program with javascript#_";`

   This Step is easy, as you can see `all text` has `selected` so, there we only have to mark all one time.

**What I did:**

```
let stringVal = "Hello friends, let's _#program#_ with _#javascript language#_";
stringVal = stringVal.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
const search = 'Hello friends'.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
console.log('before: ', stringVal);
let copyString = stringVal;
copyString = copyString.replace(/_#(\w+(?: \w+)*)#_/g, "$1");
copyString = copyString.replace(search, `_#${search}#_`);
console.log('aafter: ', copyString);
```

Above code result is: `_#Hello friends#_, let's program with javascript language`.

Correct one is: `_#Hello friends#_, let_'s _#program#_ with _#javascript language#_`.

Here I couldn't find a stable solution, in my solutions it removes all previous style, and styles again only apply on only current selected text.

But I want to save the status of previous selected text and add new style, if there was any overlap, then it will be overridden.

**Also If there is library to do this things you can suggest me**

[My Last try](https://playcode.io/595232):

I once tried to save the index of all marked style, then compare it with index of current selected text, but it is also didn't respond as well, code is here.